# Google sign in without any fragments? If not, how T do I create a "Fragment"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, google-signin

I've recently tried implementing Google Sign in. The problem is I'm not much of a fan of `Fragment`s, and I'm stuck at this line in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#before_you_begin):

> Then, also in your sign-in activity's onCreate method, create a GoogleApiClient object with access to the Google Sign-In API and the options you specified.
>
> ```
>     // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
> // options specified by gso.
> mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
>         .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
>         .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
>         .build();
> ```

---

I know, I know, Stack Overflow isn't much of a "walk-me-through" kind of thing. So here's my question, since this isn't mentioned in the blog: How do I create the fragment needed for this layout?

The comment: `/* FragmentActivity */` clearly states I need a fragment, or maybe I **CAN** do it WITHOUT a fragment? I've easily implemented Facebook, but as usual, Google is giving me a hard time :|

---

And I'm using this along with Firebase.

Comment: Is there a problem with just using Activity instead of FragmentActivity?

Comment: [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`.  If your already using it, you're good to go.

Comment: @qbix I'm using it, but AS tells me I can't use "`this`" in `enableAutoManage` in the first parameter.

Comment: Is the code in a callback?  You may need to qualify `this` with the activity class name, like `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: @qbix thanks, post this as the answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fragment is not needed. [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`.  If you are using `AppCompatactivity`,  it can be used as the first argument to `enableAutoManage()`.